# powershell - iterate over json keys that have similar name

Tags: json, powershell

I have a json block containing keys that have a similar name, each is numbered. I want to iterate over those keys. How can this be achieved?

Eg

```
$json = @"
{
    "output": [
            {
                "AIeventCheck1": "A",
                "AIeventCheck2": "B",
                "AIeventCheck3": "C"
            }
    ]

}
"@

$config = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

ForEach ($AIeventCheck in $config.output) {

    Write-host AIeventCheck value: $AIeventCheck

}
```

target output:
A
B
C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `psobject` memberset to access the individual properties of the object(s):

```
foreach($AIeventCheck in $config.output){
  $AIEventCheckValues = $AIEventCheck.psobject.Properties |Where Name -like 'AIeventCheck*' |ForEach-Object Value

  Write-Host AIeventCheck value: $AIeventCheckValues
}
```